# Applying percentage in one dataframe to columns in other data frame to create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am new to python so maybe a silly and easy question.

I have two data frames, the first data frame have a percentage column which needs to applied on column A, B, C in Dataframe2. Any suggestions ?

Dataframe 1

Region      Percentage

South       34.4%

North       27.0%

West        21.2%

Eastern     14.8%

other       2.6%

Dataframe 2
Week ending Upper Limit Forecasted value    Lower Limit State   Forecasting Date

22/05/2022  2112.2  2316.4  2525.9  CA  30/05/2022

29/05/2022  2123.8  2331.1  2523.4  CA  30/05/2022

5/06/2022   2136.5  2340.5  2553.8  CA  30/05/2022

12/06/2022  2148.466667 2353.433333 2562.266667 CA  30/05/2022

19/06/2022  2160.616667 2365.483333 2576.216667 CA  30/05/2022

26/06/2022  2172.766667 2377.533333 2590.166667 CA  30/05/2022

Desired Data frame

Region  Week ending Upper Limit Forecasted value    Lower Limit State   Forecasting Date

South   22/05/2022  726.6   796.8   868.9   CA  30/05/2022

North   22/05/2022  570.3   625.4   682.0   CA  30/05/2022

West    22/05/2022  447.8   491.1   535.5   CA  30/05/2022

Eastern     22/05/2022  312.6   342.8   373.8   CA  30/05/2022

other   22/05/2022  54.9    60.2    65.7    CA  30/05/2022

South   29/05/2022  730.6   801.9   868.0   CA  30/05/2022

North   29/05/2022  573.4   629.4   681.3   CA  30/05/2022

West    29/05/2022  450.2   494.2   535.0   CA  30/05/2022

Eastern     29/05/2022  314.3   345.0   373.5   CA  30/05/2022

other   29/05/2022  55.2    60.6    65.6    CA  30/05/2022

South   5/06/2022   735.0   805.1   878.5   CA  30/05/2022

North   5/06/2022   576.9   631.9   689.5   CA  30/05/2022

West    5/06/2022   452.9   496.2   541.4   CA  30/05/2022

Eastern     5/06/2022   316.2   346.4   378.0   CA  30/05/2022

other   5/06/2022   55.5    60.9    66.4    CA  30/05/2022

Please find below excel image, hopefully above data with excel image would make more sense. I would have love to attach excel if they would have let me. Thanks in advance on any assistance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQCHy.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We can't copy/paste from an image. So copy /paste from excel to here like this we can reproduce in our own IDE :)

Comment: @Drakax thank you for your response. I have added data frames structure. Hopefully it will help you. excel image is still there hopefully data and image together would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Because we don't have common keys (*columns*), we can't merge them, so the trick is to make both DF same size.

**1.1** Make df1 to 30 rows, repeating same row block:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*6, ignore_index=True)
```

**1.2** Make df2 to 30 rows repeating by `index` this time:

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(5)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**2.** Now that we have 2 dfs with same size (*length*), we can `concat()` them:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

**3.** Time now to multiply the 3 columns by the "Percentage" (*I've removed the **"%"** to make it easier*) one:

```
df3[["Upper Limit", "Forecasted value", 'Lower limit']] = (df3[["Upper Limit", "Forecasted value", 'Lower limit']].multiply(df3["Percentage"], axis="index")/100).round(1)
df3
```